# Is it bad practice to set mongodb object id to a 'String' instead of 'Schema.Types.ObjectId'?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to know if this can affect performance or other important matters in terms of functionality especially when finding documents in a mongodb collection

I have done this

```
var ComputerArticleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
```

its commonly done like this

```
_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Not performance but when you have more than two model and they have their association then how can you link between them. So, it is necessary. And you don't have to manually define(write) like you did, mongodb automatically create the _id.

Answer (score 0):

_id is created automatically!

If you are referencing other table use 'table_id' (or some other key name) and give type as Schema.Types.ObjectId or Schema.ObjectId.

```
const ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

user_id: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing strings rather than ObjectIds **does** hurt performance.

ObjectIds are **smaller** than the equivalent strings (they are a 12 byte binary value rather than a 24 character UTF-8 string value), so they take up less space in memory.

Mongo is really fast when indexes & documents are in the working set (i.e. in memory) so by lowering the data footprint, you're able to make sure that more documents stay in memory. This is especially important because the id fields that you're talking about are often included in indexes.